# How to move a value from one ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to move a specific value from an array list to another, what is the best way to go about doing this? Here is some example code:

values from

```
ArrayList<CreateCard> deckArray = new ArrayList<CreateCard>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<CreateCard> playerHand = new ArrayList<CreateCard>();
```

Comment: Remove the object from the first list and add it to the second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of helper functions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<CreateCard> deckArray = new ArrayList<CreateCard>();
    deckArray.add(new CreateCard());
    deckArray.add(new CreateCard());

    ArrayList<CreateCard> playerHand = new ArrayList<CreateCard>();

    // Deal a card
    moveASpecificValue(deckArray, playerHand, 0);

    // Deal from the bottom of the deck
    moveASpecificValue(deckArray, playerHand, deckArray.size() - 1);
}

public static void moveASpecificValue( List<CreateCard> source, 
                                       List<CreateCard> destination, 
                                       int indexOfSpecificValue) {
    destination.add(source.remove(indexOfSpecificValue));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the index i where the CreateCard is stored in DeckArray, you can just do:

```
PlayerHand.add(DeckArray.remove(i));
```

Comment: Essentially I am trying to move a card from the top of the deck to the player's hand (so it would completely remove it from the deck, and then move it into the player's hand).

Comment: You can not use `ArrayList.remove(Object o)` as it returns `true` if the object was found and `false` if it wasn't found. You can remove by index however. I recommend doing it in three lines however.

Comment: My apologies, I noticed that as well and edited it. If you are just attempting to remove the top card, would DeckArray.remove(0) work?

Answer (score 1):

Some things first.

- `CreateCard` is a class representing what? If it just represents a card then I'd name the class `Card` to avoid confusion.
- Variables in java (just as methods) are usually named with lowerCamelCase meaning `DeckArray` to `deckArray`.
- I recommend naming it to `deckOfCards` instead of `deckArray` as `deckArray` could be interpenetrated as an array of decks.
- Can your array ever contain duplicate decks? As in are you playing with more one deck of cards? If not all its members will be unique. If so I recommend using [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead or `ArrayList`.

Last the actual problem.

```
PlayerHand.add(DeckArray.remove(0));
```

That would remove the top card and add it to the PlayerHand.

Answer (score 0):

Just for loop through the ArrayList that you want to get the value from and when you come to the right index or criteria then just place the value inside the other array list.

Comment: What's the point of using a random access collection if you're going to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a function like :

```
public void moveCard(List<CreateCard> playerHand, List<CreateCard> deckArray) {

    playerHand.add(deckArray.get[0])
    deckArray.remove(0)

}
```

Hope it helps.